# Platform.Cloud.Coveo.Com doesnt have any information for my Organisation

Tags: coveo

I have newly started with the Existing coveo project where everything looks fine,Except the platform.cloud.coveo.com doesnt have any info on index etc.Its completely blank.[image]

I checked in showconfig.aspx it looks fine asbeow

cloudPlatformUri -https://platform.cloud.coveo.com
organizationId-organizationId
indexingEndpointUri-https://push.cloud.coveo.com

Please let me know how to fix this .

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to rebuild the coveo_master_index and coveo_web_index from the Sitecore Indexing Manager in order for the Coveo Cloud index to be configured and filled with items.

Comment: Hi jflheureux, Thanks for your reply .I tried this ,Rebuild was sucessfull ,But this did not help .

Comment: In that case, I believe you are not looking at the right Coveo Cloud organization in the Coveo Cloud Administration Console. There is a drop down in the site header to choose the organization. I recommend you to go in the Sitecore Control Panel, in the Coveo Search section, and click on the "Coveo Cloud administration console" link. It will open the right organization for you. If this does not work, please open a support ticket to Coveo as there must be something misconfigured.